# Office JavaScript API: scrolling within a document

Tags: ms-word, office365, ms-office, office-js

I'm working on a side project using the Microsoft Office JavaScript APIs. I have been relying on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/javascript-api-for-office) to find my way around, but I've hit a wall trying to find something in the docs (perhaps it isn't there because it doesn't exist).

Recently I was implementing programmatic scrolling to a certain position within a Word document. I am currently using the [Range.select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.range?view=office-js#select-selectionmode-) method to accomplish this, but the scrolling behavior isn't exactly what I want: the method ensures that the document scrolls so that the range is visible, but it doesn't always end up in a consistent location relative to the viewport. I.e. sometimes the range is at the bottom of the document, sometimes it's in the middle, and sometimes it's at the top.

I'm wondering: is there a way with the Office JavaScript APIs to exert more precise control over the scroll position of the document? In my ideal world, there would be something analogous to `scrollTo` (but of course I can't use `scrollTo` directly, as my add-in cannot directly access the parent window where the document is rendered).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that there isn't an API in Word.js that will control the scroll position of the document. But it is a good idea. Please suggest it at [Office Developer Suggestion Box](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).

Comment: Hey @Rick Kirkham, did this feature ever make it in the product?

Comment: No. Not yet. But Microsoft is increasing its investment in Word APIs, so there is still hope.

Answer (score 0):

am not sure scroll position of the document via Word API. But I did one thing in code to scroll to top of body when we trigger button.

```
context.document.body.getRange('Start').select();
```